# ngrx Handle list of objects, load one of them

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a problem and couldn't find a described solution.

Let say I would like to have a "slot" in store, that would store articles.

Right now I have a page, where I know I need to display two particular articles, so for each of them I have property in smart component, effect, reducer and actions.

What I'm looking for is something like common list of articles, where I can select by some property, id in most cases.

Is it a correct way? Since reducers methods should return objects that are stored, so return only one article by ID is not correct place.

Also same situation for loading an article which has to be downloaded first from API and added to the stored list. Since component displaying an article is dummy component, I cannot somehow gather all articles I would need to download prior to initialization.

Where should be this logic placed?

Thank you for any advice

Comment: This logic should be placed inside a selector. You can find plenty of tutorials about selectors on Google. Looking either for Redux or Ngrx. (don't have time to give you an example but it's really easy)

Answer (score 0):

For the first question about selecting using an id:
Put the logic in a selector or the service using a selector. You are correct, do not do this in a reducer. @ngrx/entity can do this for you automatically.

Pseudo code:

```
getArticles(): Observable<Article[]> {
  return this.store.select(this.articles);
}
getArticleById(id: number | string): Observable<Article> {
  return this.getArticles().pipe(
    take(1),
    map(articles => articles.find(a => a.id === id)),
  );
}
```

Second issue, loading stuff. Do this in an effect, then dispatch the action containing the model/response data to the reducer. If you are not using @ngrx/effects, you could do it in a service with the store injected, then dispatch the result to the store.